# Failed to load resource from gstatic.com/charts

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I use gstatic.com/charts to load graph to the web page.
But several days ago the webpage gave error

```
GET https://www.gstatic.com/charts/current/css/util/util.css
```

In **network** tab it shows that **util.css** is not loaded.

Checked via Incognito- the same problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

The JS is connected via 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'. From the JS file the CSS files are uploaded via the URL, written in that JS file.

I downloaded that JS file to include it locally, however they changed the URL of css file and this problem occured.

For me it helped to include the JS file via the above URL.